# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY and INSERT IGNORE auto_increment

Tags: mysql

Today I've learn that MySQL locks the table when ON DUPLICATE KEY or INSERT IGNORE are used + increase A_I even if no rows were affected. I understand that it positively impacts on performance, but I have a question, what happens when PK (INT type (max size: 2^32)) will reach 4294967296. Would it take new numbers from missed gaps or just return an error?

Comment: When you exceed the size, MySQL stops inserting and throws an error: `ERROR 1467 (HY000): Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine`. It never takes numbers from "gaps".

Comment: use BIGINT then you have a bigger range 2^64